# Meteor throwing "error: certificate has expired" errror even when setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, tls1.2

So since we are running our meteor on an old version, we have to disable the node tls rejection in order to get our environments to build.

Do not explain to me how this is insecure please, we get that and we are working on it.

For now though, all of the sudden, one of our developers gets the "error: certificate has expired" command everytime meteor tries to install packages.

In order to fix this, we have tried the following commands:

`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 meteor --settings settings.json`

`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 meteor --settings settings.json`

`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 && meteor --settings settings.json`

We've tried running it before the meteor command too, no luck... any idea what we're doing wrong here or any other solutions? None of the meteor docs or other stack overflow problems have helped us in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after googling for another hour, i came across an article suggesting to run this command:

`export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'`

Notice the `export` instead of set, don't know why this worked or what it did different, but yeah

Comment: I think this depends on what Operational System and bash you are using.